# Length of the primary component of $(xy, y^2)$ at the origin is $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

As the question title suggests, how do I see that the length of the primary component of $(xy, y^2)$ at the origin is $1$?

Comment: Primary component in what context?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: What "primary component" are you talking about? Your ideal decomposes as $(x,y^2)\cap(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to calculate the length of the longest ideal of finite length in the ring$$R_\mathfrak{p}/IR_\mathfrak{p}.$$For us, $\mathfrak{p} = \langle x, y\rangle$ and $I = \langle y^2, xy\rangle$. Since $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a local ring, the obvious choice of an idea of maximal length is $\langle x, y\rangle$. This ideal is a vector space of dimension one over $k$. So the length is obviously one.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. In what possible sense is $(x,y)$ a finite dimensional vectors space over $k$, let alone one dimensional?